# aggregate function with yearmon

Tags: r, aggregate, zoo

I am trying to run Below code in R

```
attach(Bilbao)
work1 <- table(Date,District)
work2 <- zoo(x=work1, order.by=as.Date(rownames(work1)))
work3 <- aggregate(x = work2, by = as.yearmon, FUN=sum)) #Error
coredata(work3) <- 100*coredata(work3) / rowSums(work3)
```

I face below error while defining work3

```
work3 <- aggregate(x = work2, by = as.Date(rownames(work2), FUN=sum))
```

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
>       arguments must have same length
>   I tried to check output of work1 and work2 and it seems as below

```
work1
            District
Date         Abando - Albia Basurto - Zorroza Begoña - Santutxu
  2004-11-17              0                 0                 1
  2004-11-19              0                 1                 0
  2004-11-24              0                 0                 0


Work2
           District
Date         Abando - Albia Basurto - Zorroza Begoña - Santutxu
  2004-11-17              0                 0                 1
  2004-11-19              0                 1                 0
```

I am unable to figure why this error occurs in work3. Please help

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by including a sample of your actual data or some toy data that produces the same behavior.

Comment: You can find the complete data set here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12DxKmHnW3FIciFW0nGSQiEpQCFSHEZG61jdD-XFRUmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can find R code file with all other files in google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6uTvvbAnvdYNmhkQzA1SlBGQWM?usp=sharing

Comment: Please review [mcve].  Do not provide links.  Cut it down into a self contained question with minimal data.